# Parallelism in VS editor extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've got a Visual Studio extension for the text editor using MEF- brace highlighting, syntax highlighting, outlining, stuff like that.

Will Visual Studio run my taggers on multiple threads for each file, or only serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio editor will only ever run your taggers serialized on the thread the `ITextBuffer` / `ITextView` is affinitized to.  Since Visual Studio only creates interesting `ITextView` / `ITextBuffer` instances on the main thread there isn't much of a threading concern here.

I was careful to say *interesting* above because at one point in time the debugger did create some `ITextBuffer` instances on background threads.  But they used a custom content type hence extensions typically didn't get bound to it.

Do note the `ITagger<T>` API is available to any extension out there.  It is technically possible for another extension to create a threading issue in a few ways

1. Request your tagger be created on another thread.  I know of no extension that does this and it would be considered bad practice.
2. Create an `ITextView` on a background thread which would consequently cause your `ITagger<T>` implementation to be created there as well.

Comment: Curious that they don't tag TextBuffers concurrently. I would design it that way. In any case, if they don't do this, it will make my life simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @DeadMG yeah it is very curious. There are a set of `ITagger<T>` implementation that can scale to the demand of `GetTags` in a very large file.  However they are far outnumbered by those which can't.  It order to have efficient taggers at scale you really have to go async in the `ITagger<T>` implementation.